# Who wrote the second tablets, God or Moshe?

Tags: moshe-rabbeinu, aseres-hadibros, tablets

I was reading in the Torah that in one place it says that God wrote the second tablets while other verses says Moshe did [Ex 34:27](https://www.sefaria.org/Exodus.34.27?ven=The_Koren_Jerusalem_Bible&vhe=Miqra_according_to_the_Masorah&lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en) and  [Deut 10:1](https://www.sefaria.org/Deuteronomy.10.1?ven=The_Koren_Jerusalem_Bible&vhe=Miqra_according_to_the_Masorah&lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en).

What is the explanation to this, since others claim it's a contradiction?

Comment: 34:27 isn't referring to the Ten Commandments (which were inscribed on the Tablets); 34:1 states (like Deut. 10:1) that G-d wrote those. It's talking about the more detailed laws in 34:11ff.

Comment: Moses *CARVED* two blank tablets, brought them up the mountain, and God inscribed them. Moses then was commanded to transcribe additional laws elsewhere. That fits with all the verses.

Comment: Moses wrote the entire Torah. I would very much like to know how you can think an incorporeal being could write a tablet lacking bodily form.

Answer (score 1):

Rabbi Meir Simcha HaKohen Dvinsk, also known as the Meshech Chochmah explains that the second tablets were for the most part written by Moshe Rabbeinu himself. But, he did it the way a human being does it. So, in order to infuse spirituality in it, G-d transformed the text of the second tablets into a divine text, just as the first set of tablets (my own, loose interpretation of this Meshech Chochmah).

[Meshech Chochmah, Parashas Ki Tisa (44):](https://www.sefaria.org/Meshekh_Chokhmah%2C_Ki_Tisa.44?ven=Yalkut,_Sifsei_Chachomim_Chumash,_Metsudah_Publications,_2009&vhe=Riga,_1927&lang=en&lookup=%D7%95%D7%9C%D7%94%D7%A9%D7%97%D7%99%D7%A8&with=Lexicon&lang2=en)

> ויאמר ד' אל משה כתב לך את הדברים האלה כו' ויכתוב על הלוחות את דברי הברית עה"ד. ובעקב בעת ההיא אמר ד' אלי פסל וכו' ואכתוב על הלוחות כו' ויכתוב על הלוחות. וכן לעיל כתוב וכתבתי על הלוחות את הדברים אשר היו על הלוחות הראשונים אשר שברת. הענין כי אלמלא חטאו בעגל ולא נשתברו לוחות ראשונות לא נשתכחה תורה מישראל ולא היתה אומה ולשון שולטת בהם, והביאור כי לולא זה היה הופעת אור האלקי פועל בם והיו מזוככי החומר והיו ממלכת כהנים וגוי קדוש, אבל כעת צריך כל אדם ליגע לזכך חומריותו בתכונות נפשו במדות ישרות וטהורות, גם לעמול על למוד התורה ולהשחיר את פניו כעורב, ואח"כ לאסוקי שמעתתא אליבא דהילכתא סיעתא דשמיא, וכל המקבל עליו עול תורה מעבירין ממנו עול מלכות ועול ד"א. לכן הלוחות ראשונות מעשה אלקים המה הקב"ה בעצמו עשאן (רש"י) גם הכתיבה, לא כן לוחות שניות משה פסל אותן גם הכתיבה משה כתבן כדרך כל אדם הכותב, אבל החקיקה מזה ומזה כדרך שהיה בלוחות הראשונות שזה ענין נסיי ונפלא כמאמרם ז"ל שמ"ם וסמ"ך שבלוחות בנס היו עומדין, זה היה מפועל אלקי כדי להראות שהחומר צריך אדם לזכך אותו, וירמוז שגם הכתיבה הוא להכנה ממפעל האדם, אח"כ לחקיקה הוא מצד עזר הקב"ה ולכן כתוב ויכתוב על שני הלוחות כמכתב הראשון, היינו שהיו חקוקין מזה ומזה חרות על הלוחות מזה ומזה ודו"ק.

See also: [Who Engraved the Second Tablets?](https://www.chabad.org/parshah/article_cdo/aid/1442959/jewish/Who-Engraved-the-Second-Tablets.htm)

In a similair vain, the Midrash [(Devarim Rabbah 3:12)](https://www.sefaria.org/Devarim_Rabbah.3.12?ven=Sefaria_Community_Translation&vhe=Midrash_Rabbah_--_TE&lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en) asks the question "who wrote this document", and responds with "Moshe":

> **And who wrote this document? Moshe. Whence? As it says (Deut. 31:9),
> "Moses wrote down this (Song) Teaching."** And what payment did the Holy
> One Blessed be He provide for him? The splendor of his face, as it is
> written (Ex. 34:29), "Moses was not aware that the skin of his face
> was radiant" -- when? "when He spoke with him." Resh Lakish said, "At
> the time he wrote the Torah, Moshe acquired the splendor of his face."
> How? Resh Lakish said,"The Torah was given to Moshe, its skin of white
> fire and written with black fire, and sealed in fire, and wrapped with
> fire. And while he was writing, he wiped his pen-reed on his hair, and
> from there he acquired the splendor of his face." (emphasis mine)

See also the commentary of the [Ibn Ezra on Shemos 32:12](https://www.sefaria.org/Ibn_Ezra_on_Exodus.32.12.1?ven=Ibn_Ezra%27s_commentary_on_the_Pentateuch,_tran._and_annot._by_H._Norman_Strickman_and_Arthur_M._Silver._Menorah_Pub.,_1988-2004&vhe=On_Your_Way&lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en):

> G-d then wrote the second tablets.

Answer (score 0):

[Ki Sisa 34:27](https://www.chabad.org/library/bible_cdo/aid/9895/showrashi/true#v27)

> The Lord said to Moses: "Inscribe these words for yourself, for
> according to these words I have formed a covenant with you and with
> Israel."

**RASHI**

> **these words:** But you are not permitted to write down the Oral Torah. -[from Gittin 60b]

This refers to the *Torah Shebichsav* (Written Torah) not to the two tablets of the ten commandments as we see in the next verse.
[Ki Sisa 27:28](https://www.chabad.org/library/bible_cdo/aid/9895/showrashi/true#v28)

> He was there with the Lord for forty days and forty nights; he ate no
> bread and drank no water, and He inscribed upon the tablets the words
> of the Covenant, the Ten Commandments.

Hashem inscribed the two new tablets Himself. Moshe spent the forty days writing the Torah itself and studying the *halacha*